# How to add a time value to a datetime value in Python?

Tags: python, excel, datetime

I have a simple question (at least I thought so), I want to add a time value to a datetime value in Python. The values are read from an excel file.

I have the following code:

```
import xlrd
from datetime import time, datetime, timedelta
book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\eline\Documents\***\***\Python\Example 1.xlsx')
sh = book.sheet_by_name("test")

arr_time = datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(sh.cell_value(1,2), book.datemode))
print(arr_time)

a2 = sh.cell_value(1,5)
# converting float from excel to time value
print(int(a2*24*3600))
x = int(a2*24*3600)
slack_time = time(x//3600, (x%3600)//60, x%60)
print(slack_time)

new_arr_time = arr_time + slack_time
print(new_arr_time)
```

arr_time is here a datetime value which can vary e.g.:

```
2016-08-28 13:10:00
```

slack_time is here a time in minutes (sometimes hours) which can vary e.g.:

```
00:15:00
```

I would like to add the slack time (e.g. 15 minutes) to the arr_time. Thus for this example I would like to get the following output for new_arr_time:

```
2016-08-28 13:25:00
```

However, when running my code I get the following error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: ‘datetime.datetime’ and ‘datetime.time’". 
From this, I understand that I cannot add a time value to a datetime value, but when converting slack_time to a datetime value and then adding slack_time to arr_time I get a similar error (although subtracting works that way). I know I can use timedelta(minutes = 15) but since the values from the excel file vary and sometimes contain hours this does not work for me.

So my question is: how can I add a time value which is read from excel to a datetime value?

Comment: The `slack_time` value read from the file is in what format? Days?

Comment: in a time format, it does not have any date at the moment. Although I tried that too and it still does not work.

Comment: I meant the float from your file

Comment: I am sorry but I don't really understand what you mean by that, do you mean the value from excel before converting it to time? That number is: 0.010416666666666666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make float value you're using to build `slack_time` into a time duration i.e. a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object. Then it can be added to the `datetime` object:

```
>>> x = 0.010416666666666666
>>> timedelta(days=x)
datetime.timedelta(0, 900)
>>> 900/60
15 # the fifteen minutes you had earlier
```

So your code becomes:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

new_arr_time = arr_time + timedelta(days=float(sh.cell_value(1,5)))
```

Comment: If I am doing this I get an error that 'datetime.datetime has no attribute timedelta?' Do you know why I get this, I thought I imported everything I need from the module.

Comment: @Eline `timedelta` is in the `datetime` module. See update.

Comment: Nevermind I already solved it. I think that this might work, although I rather want to just read the value from excel without converting it in timedelta, but I don't think that is a possible option. Finally, can you please explain why you put the 0 before 900 in timedelta? Does this has anything to do with days? And thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: @Eline It's the date part of the `timedelta`. And I didn't put it there, Python did :)

Comment: Ah I see, Python is wonderful haha. However, thank you a lot, this solution is easy to read and works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime
arr_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-08-28 13:10:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
slack_time="00:15:00"
hrs,mts=slack_time.split(":")[:2]
new_time = arr_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=int(hrs),minutes=int(mts))
```

Your can get back the date in the string format if you want from `new_time`

Comment: Why make a round trip with the string object, when you can easily build the `timedelta` from the float.

Comment: Thank your for your effort but I think I will go with the first answer since it is easier for me to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one - Hope it works

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(arr_time, "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S")
mtime = str(d.hour) + ':' + str(d.minute) + ':' + str(d.second) # Split the time from DateTime and store to a variable named mtime
mdate = str(d.year) + '-' + str(d.month) + '-' + str(d.day) # Store the date into a variable named mdate

timeList = [ mtime, slack_time ]
totalSecs = 0
for tm in timeList:
    timeParts = [int(s) for s in tm.split(':')]
    totalSecs += (timeParts[0] * 60 + timeParts[1]) * 60 + timeParts[2]
totalSecs, sec = divmod(totalSecs, 60)
hr, min = divmod(totalSecs, 60)

ntime = "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hr, min, sec)
print ntime
mergedTime = mdate + ' ' + ntime
print 'Merged Date/Time is: ', mergedTime
```